# Unbiased sample standard deviation of a custom/unknown probability distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

Hi i must determine the unbiased sample standard deviation of an unknown probability distribution.I dont have the data of the full population so i must work with a sample.

Now according to Wikipedia this is the best formula which would calculate it:

[Wikipedia page of the unbiased estimation of SD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation)

$$\hat{\sigma}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1.5-\frac{1}{4} \gamma_{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)^{2}}$$

The dilemma with this is that i dont know which formula of the kurtosis to use:

The $\gamma_2$ denotes the "excess kurtosis", but should it be the **excess kurtosis of the sample** or of the **entire population** ?  According to wikipedia it should be for the entire population, however that doesnt seem logical, as the formula is based on the sample.

Please clarify and help me , thanks :)

Comment: You always have to assume that your sample is representative of the distribution. Either you know the kurtosis of the distribution, or you don't, in which case you need to estimate it, from the sample. You will unfortunately have the same issue now to estimate your kurtosis.

Comment: My sample is representative of the distribution, and yes i dont know the kurtosis because as i said the distribution is not a known distribution, so i have to estimate the kurtosis from the sample. So should i use the excess kurtosis of the sample or of the population (as Wikipedia suggests), please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the article you reference does not guarantee the unbiasedness of the estimator in your post. A good approach in this situation is to jacknife or bootstrap correct the bias. Unlike the sample variance estimate, the sample standard deviation estimator bias is very sensitive to the actual distribution (or family of distributions).

Comment: How should i proceed then, do you have any links to academic papers which found better estimation of an unbiased SD, or can you please give me an advice how should i proceed?

Comment: @Mr.Curious Here is a nice intro to boostrap theory, with a specific example on how to use it for bias reduction: http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~peterh/sta251/bootstrap-lectures-to-may-16.pdf  [see page 11]